# Laravel Factory: Manual Increment of Column

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-seeding

For the following factory definition, the column `order` needs to be sequential. There is already a column `id` that is auto-incremented. The first row's `order` should start at `1` and each additional row's `order` should be the next number (`1`,`2`,`3`, etc.)

```
$factory->define(App\AliasCommand::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'user_id' => App\User::inRandomOrder()->first()->id,
        'command' => $faker->word,
        'content' => $faker->sentence,
        'order'   => (App\AliasCommand::count()) ?
            App\AliasCommand::orderBy('order', 'desc')->first()->order + 1 : 1
    ];
});
```

It should be setting the `order` column to be 1 more than the previous row, however, it results in all rows being assigned `1`.

Comment: Are you ok with getting duplicate values for the order field? This solution you have doesn't prevent race conditions.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Here's something that might work.

```
$factory->define(App\AliasCommand::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    static $order = 1;   
    return [
        'user_id' => App\User::inRandomOrder()->first()->id,
        'command' => $faker->word,
        'content' => $faker->sentence,
        'order'   => $order++
    ];
});
```

It just keeps a counter internal to that function.

##### Update:

Laravel 8 introduced new factory classes so this request becomes:

```
class AliasCommandFactory extends Factory {

    private static $order = 1;

    protected $model = AliasCommand::class;

    public function definition() {
         $faker = $this->faker;
         return [
            'user_id' => User::inRandomOrder()->first()->id,
            'command' => $faker->word,
            'content' => $faker->sentence,
            'order'   => self::$order++
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The answer by @apokryfos is a good solution if you're sure the factory model generations will only be run in sequential order and you're not concerned with pre-existing data.

However, this can result in incorrect `order` values if, for example, you want to generate models to be inserted into your test database, where some records already exist.

Using a closure for the column value, we can better automate the sequential order.

```php
$factory->define(App\AliasCommand::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'user_id' => App\User::inRandomOrder()->first()->id,
        'command' => $faker->word,
        'content' => $faker->sentence,
        'order'   => function() {
            $max = App\AliasCommand::max('order'); // returns 0 if no records exist.

            return $max+1;
        }
    ];
});
```

You almost had it right in your example, the problem is that you were running the `order` value execution *at the time of defining the factory* rather than the above code, which executes *at the time the individual model is generated*.

By the same principle, you should also enclose the `user_id` code in a closure, otherwise all of your factory generated models will have the same user ID.

Comment: I am on laravel 8 currently. max returns null when no records exist.

Answer (score 5):

In Laravel 9 (and possibly some earlier versions?), there's a pretty clean way to make this happen when you're creating models ([from the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-factories#sequences)):

```php
$users = User::factory()
    ->count(10)
    ->sequence(fn ($sequence) => ['order' => $sequence->index])
    ->create();
```

If you'd like to start with `1` instead of `0`:

```php
$users = User::factory()
    ->count(10)
    ->sequence(fn ($sequence) => ['order' => $sequence->index + 1])
    ->create();
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve true autoIncrement rather use this approach:

```
   $__count = App\AliasCommand::count();
   $__lastid = $__count ? App\AliasCommand::orderBy('order', 'desc')->first()->id : 0 ;


   $factory->define(App\AliasCommand::class,
       function(Faker\Generator $faker) use($__lastid){

       return [

         'user_id' => App\User::inRandomOrder()->first()->id,
         'command' => $faker->word,
         'content' => $faker->sentence,
         'order'   => $faker->unique()->numberBetween($min=$__lastid+1, $max=$__lastid+25),

         /*  +25 (for example here) is the number of records you want to insert 
             per run.
             You can set this value in a config file and get it from there
             for both Seeder and Factory ( i.e here ).
         */
      ];

   });
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution also solves **already data on table** conditions:

```php
class UserFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = User::class;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected static int $id = 0;

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        if ( self::$id == 0 ) {
            self::$id = User::query()->max("id") ?? 0;
            // Initialize the id from database if exists.
            // If conditions is necessary otherwise it would return same max id.
        }

        self::$id++;

        return [
            "id"        => self::$id,
            "email"      => $this->faker->email,
        ];
    }
}
```